# How to send a link in an SMS so that the preview is loaded automatically?

Tags: ios, sms, twilio

I am using twilio to send SMS messages to phone numbers. What I am having problems with is making sure that once a user gets the message the preview of what is at a certain link actually loads in the message the user sees on the phone.

What is the proper way to send a link that automatically shows the preview?

EDIT:

I tried the open graph api. Apple does have a tech note on that. But, then, why does this link provided a proper preview in messages when I send this link to another phone? It works, and it does not use open graph.

https://i1.wp.com/www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/2018-Ducati-Panigale-V4-29.jpg?ssl=1

Comment: Check twilio if they support Wap Push SMS.

Answer (score 2):

a couple of things you can try

1. have the link at start of the message or end of the message
2. the link should be properly formatted with either http:// or https://
3. iOS uses The Open Graph protocol to support what image to show in the link . http://ogp.me/